# C++ Practice on STL templates and algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, homework, stl

I have implemented the following program below for an assignment for practice on STL templates and algorithms. All I'm doing is implementing the code for the printing of empty files, un-empty files, etc.. I would love to know if there is any way to make the code more optimized.

Note: From the requirements of my school (Must be adhered to):

- Code with the comment "helper function" should **not** be modified. These are `empty_check()`, `split()`, and `print_filename()`.
- Functions commented as "Can modify" means the code within that function can be modified.
- `int main()` should **not** be modified
- No extra headers allowed.
- No definition of any new complex types or templates
- No using of other functions other than the helper functions.
- No use of lambda expressions.
- No use of operators:

  - `.` (member access)
  - `->` (member access via a pointer)
  - `*` (dereference).
- No use of explicit iteration (`for`, `while`, `do while`) or selection (`if`, `switch`, `?:`) statements or operators.
- No use of keyword `auto`.
- No use of `std::cout`, `std::cerr` or any other functions that perform printing of the text. I'll have to use the provided helper function to do it.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using name_file = std::string;
using sizeFile = size_t;
using record_in_file = std::pair<name_file, sizeFile>;
using file_datas = std::map<name_file, sizeFile>;

bool empty_check( //helper function
    const record_in_file& dataRecord,
    bool true_if_its_not
)
{
    sizeFile size;
    std::tie(std::ignore, size) = dataRecord;
    bool result = (size == 0);
    if (true_if_its_not)
    {
        result = !result;
    }
    return result;
}

name_file split(const record_in_file& dataRecord) //helper function
{
    name_file name;
    std::tie(name, std::ignore) = dataRecord;
    return name;
}

void print_filename(const name_file& name1) //helper function
{
    std::cout << " * " << name1 << std::endl;
}

void file_names_print(const file_datas& map1) //can modify 
{
    std::vector<name_file> files;
    std::transform(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1), std::back_inserter(files), split);
    std::for_each(std::begin(files), std::end(files), print_filename);
}

size_t files_un_empty_print(const file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    std::vector<record_in_file> files;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1), std::back_inserter(files),
        std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));
    std::vector<name_file> file_names;
    std::transform(std::begin(files), std::end(files), std::back_inserter(file_names),
        split);
    std::for_each(std::begin(file_names), std::end(file_names), print_filename);

    return std::count_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1),
        std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));
}

size_t files_empty_print(const file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    std::vector<record_in_file> files;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1), std::back_inserter(files),
        std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, false));

    std::vector<name_file> file_names;
    std::transform(std::begin(files), std::end(files), std::back_inserter(file_names),
        split);

    std::for_each(std::begin(file_names), std::end(file_names), print_filename);

    return std::count_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1),
        std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, false));
}

std::tuple<file_datas&>  get_param(file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple<file_datas&>(map1);
}

void empty_removal(file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    std::vector<record_in_file> files;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1), std::back_inserter(files),
        std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));

    file_datas n_map{ std::begin(files),std::end(files) };

    std::swap(map1, n_map);
}


int main()
{
    file_datas map = {
        {"readme.txt", 2000},
        {"main.exe", 10000},
        {"save.bak", 0},
        {"library.dll", 1243},
        {"0.res", 121100},
        {"1.res", 121100},
        {"2.res", 115600},
        {"errors.log", 0}
    };

    std::cout << "Files:" << std::endl;
    file_names_print(map);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Files that are not empty:" << std::endl;
    size_t Count_of_unemptyFiles = files_un_empty_print(map);
    std::cout
        << " There are "
        << Count_of_unemptyFiles
        << " non-empty files.\n"
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Files that are empty:" << std::endl;
    size_t Count_of_emptyFiles = files_empty_print(map);
    std::cout
        << " There are "
        << Count_of_emptyFiles
        << " empty files.\n"
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Files after removing the empty ones:" << std::endl;
    auto parameters = get_param(map);
    std::apply(empty_removal, parameters);
    file_names_print(map);
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid creating temporary vectors

You should avoid creating unnecessary temporary vectors. For example, in `file_names_print()`, you can use a nested `std::bind()` to avoid the vector `files`:

```
void file_names_print(const file_datas& map1) //can modify 
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1),
                  std::bind(print_filename, std::bind(split, std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

This can be done with all the `std::transform()` + `std::for_each()` combinations. Given the restrictions you have, I don't see how to avoid the temporary vectors for `std::copy_if`.

## Avoid unnecessary counting

In those cases where you used `std::copy_if()`, you then no longer need to call `std::count_if()` to count matching elements in the original input, you can just get the `std::size()` of the temporary vector. For example:

```
size_t files_un_empty_print(const file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    std::vector<record_in_file> files;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1), std::back_inserter(files), std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));
    std::for_each(std::begin(files), std::end(files), std::bind(print_filename, std::bind(split, std::placeholders::_1)));

    return std::size(files);
}
```

## Removing elements from a container

If you can use C++20, then you would simply write:

```
void empty_removal(file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    std::erase_if(map1, std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));
}
```

If you cannot use C++20, then the typical way would be to use a `for`-loop that calls `erase()` on matching elements. Of course, you are restricted from doing that, and then you indeed have to make a copy.

## Copy directly into a `std::map`

In `empty_removal()`, you first create a `std::vector` of files, and then convert that to a map. That can be avoided by creating an empty `std::map` and inserting in that instead:

```
void empty_removal(file_datas& map1) //can modify
{
    file_datas files;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(map1), std::end(map1),
                std::inserter(files, std::end(files)),
                std::bind(empty_check, std::placeholders::_1, true));

    std::swap(map1, files);
}
```

## About those restrictions

It might be a way to force you to use STL algorithms, but there are several drawbacks. Unfortunately, due to the fact you have to pass multiple iterators to STL algorithms, and never get a container as a return value, it is very hard to compose multiple STL algorithms. You then have to use intermediate copies, which is very inefficient. A [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is then usually clearer and more efficient. In the real world, you would be able to use all the tools that C++ provides, and select the ones that are most appropriate to the task. You would likely combine `for`-loops, algorithms and lambdas.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the much needed suggestions! Anyway, for the 'empty_removal()", std::inserter is part of #include<iterator> header which is not covered in any of the headers above. *No extra headers allowed*. Any other substitute for std::inserter? I tried back_inserter intuitively, but of course, it doesn't work for all container types, std::map, etc..

Comment: @starrk It compiles for me without explicitly including `<iterator>` when using GCC (version 10.2.0) or Clang (version 10.0.1). And you were already using `std::back_inserter`, which is also part of `<iterator>`. Technically, if you are not able to add `#include <iterator>`, then you cannot safely use any iterator class. If it works it is only through luck that another header includes it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for being a bit brief with this review, however, my time is limited
today. My review is a bit less technical than G. Sliepen's and is focused more
on code style.

### Prefer consistent names

Looking at the first two lines after the list of includes:

```cpp
using name_file = std::string;
using sizeFile = size_t;
...
```

Pick a style (`two_words`, `twoWords`, `TwoWords`, etc.) and stick with it
throughout your code.

### Choose names which improve code readability and follow proper grammar

```cpp
size_t files_un_empty_print(const file_datas& map1);  // what does "files_un_empty" mean?
void file_names_print(const file_datas& map1);        // what is "map_1"?
bool empty_check(
    const record_in_file& dataRecord,
    bool true_if_its_not // "is_empty" is concise and better communicates the intent
);
void empty_removal(file_datas& map1);  // "remove" or "delete_empty_files" are clearer
```

For the second point about proper grammar, this may be an insignificant nitpick
on my part, however, if you can use proper English grammar when choosing names,
do so:

```cpp
using name_file = std::string;  // "file_name" is a more natural and familiar way to say the same thing
using file_datas = std::map<name_file, sizeFile>;  // the word "data" is plural
```

There may be additional examples in your code but this should illustrate the
point.

### Using declarations

You created an alias:

```cpp
using sizeFile = size_t;
```

and then reverted to using `size_t`:

```cpp
size_t files_un_empty_print(const file_datas& map1);
```